# How many different ways can you allocate money into 5 buckets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many different ways can you invest $\$N,000$ into Y funds?

So for example if $N=20000$ and $Y=5$ we could have $(0,4000,1000,2000,13000)$

I know this has something to do with combinatorics but I am lost.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: You can also consider coin change problem which is solvable with dynamic programming.

Comment: You really should clarify the minimum positive amount that can be invested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investment are in multiple of 1000.
$$ $$
Let investment in different funds are $x_1;x_2;x_3;x_4;x_5$
$$ $$
Number of ways is number of non negative integral solution of equation 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=20$$
Number of ways are $$={24 \choose 20}$$
For more understanding of concept you can also refer 
https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/distribution-of-identical-objects-into-distinct-groups/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the investments can be made in multiples of thousands, using [Stars and Bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) we arrive to the answer :   $^{N+Y-1}C_{Y-1}$